# select from the tables with grouping

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

I want to select list of objects that look like this

```
class CategoryProduct { 
    String id
    String name
    List<String> products
}
```

In my mapper file I have this code

```
<resultMap type="CategoryProduct" id="categoryProductMap">
    <id property="id" column="cpm_category"/>
    <result property="name" column="c_name"/>
    <collection property="products" ofType="string" column="cpm_license_product"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getProductsForAllCategories" resultMap="categoryProductMap">
    SELECT
        cpm.category_uid cpm_category,
        c.name c_name,
        cpm.pm_license_product_uid cpm_license_product
    FROM ${schema}.category_product_map cpm
        INNER JOIN ${schema}.category c
            ON c.category_uid = cpm.category_uid
    GROUP BY cpm_category, c_name, cpm_license_product
</select>
```

I invoke selection like this

```
getTemplate().selectList(getNamespace() +".getProductsForAllCategories");
```

I expect this result

```
id: CATEGORY_1,
name: 'first category',
products: [PRODUCT_1, PRODUCT_2]
```

But the result I get looks like this

```
id: CATEGORY_1,
name: 'first category',
products: [CATEGORY_1, CATEGORY_1]
```

Instead of returning products it duplicates `ids` in `products` field. Why is that? What is the problem?

`GROUP BY` is needed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `resultMap` to

```
<resultMap type="CategoryProduct" id="categoryProductMap">
    <id property="id" column="cpm_category"/>
    <result property="name" column="c_name"/>
    <collection property="products" ofType="string" javaType="java.util.ArrayList">
        <result column="cpm_license_product"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

and it started to work.